# Can't see vertices

Tags: vertices

I was using Blender (2.80) and I accidentally pressed something and couldn't see vertices, only edges.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You are in *Edge Selection* mode (hot key <kbd>2</kbd> on the keyboard). To go back to verticies press <kbd>1</kbd> on the keyboard or use the buttons at the top in the 3D viewport:

[image]

Comment: Thank You Very Much!!!

Comment: @DragonBoy.exe Consider to accept the answer: https://blender.stackexchange.com/tour